# PHP Laravel recursive function with nested array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using `Laravel 4` with `MySQL` back-end.

I want to store records of a `nested array` into database using `recursive function`.

The input array is as below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        'id' => 561,
        'type' => 'q',
        'subtype' => 'boolean',
        'title' => 'Did you..?',
        'parent' => 560,
        'created_at' => '2014-07-09 09:45:50',
        'updated_at' => NULL,
        'deleted_at' => NULL,
        'children' => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        'id' => 562,
                        'type' => 'o',
                        'subtype' => NULL,
                        'title' => 'Yes',
                        'parent' => 561,
                        'created_at' => '2014-07-09 09:45:50',
                        'updated_at' => NULL,
                        'deleted_at' => NULL,
                        'children' => Array
                            (
                            )
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        'id' => 563,
                        'type' => 'answer',
                        'subtype' => NULL,
                        'title' => 'No',
                        'parent' => 561,
                        'created_at' => '2014-07-09 09:45:50',
                        'updated_at' => 'NULL',
                        'deleted_at' => NULL,
                        'children' => Array
                            (
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

The `recursive function` I am using store the records into the database is as below :

```
public function addRecursiveChildren(array $surveychildren, $parentid, $userid){

    foreach ($surveychildren as $item) 
    {
        /* Error : HTTPRequest Error :: 500: {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Cannot use a scalar value as an array
           Error is in the statement below in the second recursion when child is passes as an input.
        */
        $item['survey_id'] = $item['id']; 
        $item['user_id'] = $userid;
        $item['id'] = null; 
        $item['parent'] = $parentid; 

        $routine = routine::create($item);

        if(count($item["children"]) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($item["children"] as $child) 
            {
                /* The $child I found is as below : 
                $child = array(
                    'id' => 562,
                    'type' => 'o',
                    'subtype' => NULL ,
                    'title' => 'Yes',
                    'parent' => 561,
                    'created_at' => '2014-07-09 09:45:50',
                    'updated_at' => NULL,
                    'deleted_at' => NULL,
                    'children' => Array
                        (
                        )
                );
                */

                RoutineRepository::addRecursiveChildren($child, $routine->id, $userid);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

I know that cause of error is the `$child` I am passing as an `input array` to the `recursive function` above :

The `$child` is something like this :

```
array(
    'id' => 562,
    'type' => 'o',
    'subtype' => NULL ,
    'title' => 'Yes',
    'parent' => 561,
    'created_at' => '2014-07-09 09:45:50',
    'updated_at' => NULL,
    'deleted_at' => NULL,
    'children' => Array
    (
    )
)
```

Instead of this if `$child` will be something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    array(
        'id' => 562,
        'type' => 'o',
        'subtype' => NULL ,
        'title' => 'Yes',
        'parent' => 561,
        'created_at' => '2014-07-09 09:45:50',
        'updated_at' => NULL,
        'deleted_at' => NULL,
        'children' => Array
        (
        )
    )
)
```

Then there will be no error.

Can anybody help me to overcome it?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe all you need is a simple insert multiple times http://laravel.com/docs/queries#inserts ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a recursive function, Laravel can handle multiple insertions at one time

Comment: I cannot add it directly because I need to insert it with parent child relationship in a self-referencing table. I am not sure if it will handle this relationship automatically.

Comment: Is the parent ID for the batch of items the same whenever you call this function, or can there be random parent IDs and children each time?

Comment: Nope. Look into the input array. By inserting the first element into the database, it will return you the primary key of that record and that primary key will be used as a parent of nested array (children) while storing record into the database.

Comment: I think I have resolved it. something like this : $c = array(); $c[0] = $child; RoutineRepository::addRecursiveChildren($c, $patient_routine->id, $userid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
class Routine extends \Eloquent
{
    // The relation
    public function subRoutine()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Routine', 'parent');
    }

    public function saveSubroutine(array $children)
    {
        foreach($children as $childData)
        {
            $child = new self($childData);
            $this->subRoutine()->save($child);

            $child->saveSubroutine($childData['children']);
        }
    }
}

$routine = Routine::create($data);
$routine->saveSubroutine($data['children']);
```

Comment: Although I have resolved it differently as mentioned in my comment of question, I am accepting it as better solution. and +1 for the efforts you did for me. Thanks.