# Laravel Eloquent get N Level hierarchy records from self-referencing table with other table's columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using `Laravel 4` with `MySQL` back-end.

I have two database tables namely - `surveyes` and `templates`.

Both of the tables are `self-referencing` and they have `column` named `parent` that is `foreign key` of that table itself. Their records are in `self referencing parent-child` relationship.

The table design is as below :

**Surveyes :**

```
(PK)                        (FK_Surveyes)
Id  title       type        parent          sort_order  deleted_at
1   General     group       NULL            1           NULL
2   Where..?    question    1               1           NULL
3   abc..       answer      2               1           NULL
4   def..       answer      2               2           NULL
5   efg..       answer      2               3           NULL
6   ghi..       answer      2               4           NULL
7   What..?     question    1               2           NULL
8   hij..       answer      7               1           NULL
9   ijk..       answer      7               2           NULL
10  How..?      question    8               1           NULL
11  jkl..       answer      10              1           NULL
12  mnm..       answer      10              2           NULL
13  Special     group       NULL            2           NULL
14  Whom..?     question    13              1           NULL
15  opq..       answer      14              1           NULL
16  rst..       answer      14              2           NULL
```

**Templates:**

```
(PK)(FK_surveyes)               (FK_Templates)
Id  survey_id       type        parent          sort_order  deleted_at
1   NULL            group       NULL            1           NULL
2   14              question    1               1           NULL
3   15              answer      2               1           NULL
4   16              answer      3               2           NULL
5   NULL            group       NULL            2           NULL
6   2               question    5               1           NULL
7   3               answer      6               1           NULL
8   4               answer      6               2           NULL
9   5               answer      6               3           NULL
10  6               answer      8               4           NULL
11  7               question    10              2           NULL
12  8               answer      10              1           NULL
13  9               answer      10              2           NULL
```

Now, I want their records also to be in the same manner with `N` level of hierarchy.

So that I have creates a `model` for `templates` as below :

```
class Template extends BaseModel{

    protected $table = 'templates';
    protected $softDelete = false;

    // loads only direct children - 1 level
    public function child()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('Template', 'parent');
    }

    // recursive, loads all descendants
    public function children()
    {
       return $this->child()->with('children')->orderBy('sort_order');
    }

    // parent
    public function parent()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('Template','parent');
    }

    // all ascendants
    public function parentRecursive()
    {
       return $this->parent()->with('parentRecursive');
    }
}
```

And I am using method below (which is working fine) to get the `N` level of hierarchy for templates :

```
public function getTemplates(){
    $templates = Template::with('children')
                ->whereNull('parent')
                ->orderBy('sort_order', 'ASC');

    return $templates->toJson();
}
```

But now, I want the column `title` from the `surveyes` table. The column `survey_id` in table `templates` is the `foreign key` of table `surveyes`.

How can I achieve it?

I have updated following method in `Template` model as below :

```
public function children()
{
   return $this->child()->with('children')->orderBy('sort_order')
        ->leftJoin('surveyes', 'surveyes.id', '=', 'templates.survey_id')->select('templates.*','surveyes.title');
}
```

But it **doesn't gives the hierarchical records and browser gets hang-up**. I have only **1500** records in `templates` table.

Does anybody knows how to achieve it?

**EDIT :**

I have added a method to get `Survey` model in templates as below :

```
public function survey()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('D2D\Models\Survey','survey_id');
    }
```

and updated the `children()` method as below :

```
public function children()
{
   return $this->child()
   ->with('survey','children')
   ->orderBy('sort_order');
}
```

Now I am able to get the records of `Survey` model but it returns all the column of the `Survey` as below :

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "survey_id": 522,
    "title": "Abc....?",
    "type": "question",
    "parent": 1200
    "survey": {
        "id": 522,
        "type": "question",
        "subtype": null,
        "title": "Abc....?",
        "parent": 1
    },
    "children": [{
        "id": 3,
        "survey_id": 526,
        "title": "aaa",
        "type": "answer",
        "parent": 2
        "survey": {
            "id": 526,
            "type": "answer",
            "subtype": null,
            "title": "aaa",
            "parent": 522
        },
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "survey_id": 527,
        "title": "bbb",
        "type": "answer",
        "parent": 2
        "survey": {
            "id": 527,
            "type": "answer",
            "title": "bbb",
            "parent": 522,
        },
        "children": []
    },
    ...
}
```

But I want it like below :

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "survey_id": 522,
    "title": "Abc....?", // Must be from Survey table
    "type": "question",
    "parent": 1200
    "children": [{
        "id": 3,
        "survey_id": 526,
        "title": "aaa", // Must be from Survey table
        "type": "answer",
        "parent": 2
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "survey_id": 527,
        "title": "bbb", // Must be from Survey table
        "type": "answer",
        "parent": 2
        "children": []
    },
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have tried by updating survey() method as below :

```
public function survey()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('D2D\Models\Survey','survey_id')->select(array('title'));
}
```

But in that case it gives title=NULL for each and every element.

Please let me know how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989245/php-laravel-recursive-function-with-nested-array?rq=1
The recursive methods have been defined separately. You also still need to set the relations.

Comment: That is different. I don't want to store anything but I want to get a column that is in another table. Also I think if I use it then in each for loop iteration it will make a separate database call. I can have thousands of records in future, in that case there might have a performance issue.

Comment: Did you get that error only after adding `leftJoin`?

Comment: @deczo Yes. I get this error if I use ->get() statement as I have mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but without that `leftJoin` in the relation, there is no error?

Comment: Yes. No error but I am not getting the result. It is giving some recursion array without any field of tables but with details of MySQL. In short, if I use "->select()" or "->get()" then I am not getting error.

Comment: *  In short, if I use "->select()" or "->get()" then I am getting the error.

Comment: @deczo any solution for this? Let us not confused, just concentrate on what I have and what I want to achieve. I have two tables, a model "Template" and a method "getTemplates()" that fetches data from the table. Now I want a "title" column from "surveyes" table with these records. Have you any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to do that, having so many function calls. Only solution I can thinkf of atm are manual joins, that will do the same, only with less functions.

Comment: OK.. But tell me how can I do that?

Comment: To be honest, I would consider better approach to the design you have. Check those out: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data for examples. I think nested sets or closure table would be the best solution.

Comment: @deczo I think it will be hard to me to implement this as I have thousands of records currently in live database and I cannot update them with new columns of path. Another solution is, I will get the "templates" nested array first that will have the foreign key "survey_id" and then I will make a single database call to get each record of "surveyes" table with "id" and "title" and then will add the "title" to the with "templates's" respected "survey_id". Is it possible?

Comment: @deczo I request you to help me please as I need a solution for it and I am trying since last 3 days but I am miserably failed..

Comment: @deczo Is there any solution for this..? I have tried a lot but I am misrabally failed to achieve this.. Or please can you suggest me any other way..? :(

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution to this problem is to use the Nested Sets model. This avoids the problem of recursive queries. There are two available Laravel packages that extend Eloquent to implement Nested Sets: [Laravel-NestedSet](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) and [Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum). I understand you have the issue of existing data; however, it shouldn't be too hard to make a one-time migration script. You can create new models using whichever nested sets library you pick; these models will have methods to set the parent node of a survey. You can have the new survey data in a new table (you can override the table name in Eloquent; [see here.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage) Then, write a script or protected controller action to migrate the existing surveys to the new table. It will work something like this (using the laravel-nestedset syntax; Baum is similar):

```
$oldSurveys = Survey::all();
$oldSurveys->each(function($survey) {
    $newSurvey = NestedSurvey::create(array($survey->name, $survey->type ...etc));
});

$newSurveys = NestedSurvey::whereNotNull('parent_id');
$newSurveys->each(function($survey) {
    $parent = NestedSurvey::find($survey->parent_id);
    $survey->appendTo($parent)->save();
});
```

Once you have imported all your survey into the new table, you can switch your application over to use the new models.

Now, you'll be able to fetch an arbitrarily deep hierarchy in linear time. And since your model extends Eloquent, you can get any related columns just as you normally would.

Comment: I have already used laravel baum package and it seems working fine now. Thanks a lot. +1 for your kind help.