# Laravel 5.2, Eloquent & Infinite Descendants

Tags: php, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5

I have a model `Category` which has a manyToMany relation with itself:

```
public function parentcategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_category', 'parent_category_id', 'category_id');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_category', 'category_id', 'parent_category_id');
}
```

What is the simplest way to get all of the descendant Categories?

For example:

```
Cat1
-Cat2
-Cat3
--Cat4
--Cat5
---Cat6
Cat7
-Cat8
```

If I click `Cat1` I want to get `Cat2-6`, and if I click `Cat3` I want to get `Cat4-6`.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here? I thought this would be a common problem.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "hierarchy".  Not specific to Eloquent, but this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database.

Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051501/laravel-eloquent-get-n-level-hierarchy-records-from-self-referencing-table-with.  Apparently there is a package that will implement the Nested Set Model for you, https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset